# Change author name in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

HI have 3 WinXP computers which access subversion based on a linux server. I would like to change the author name displayed in the logs on a couple of the computers cause they are 'development pc 3' and the name of an old employee. How do I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ask TSVN to "show log", in the change log order all commits by author, then select all the commits by the author of interest and use "Edit author".

Comment: what im trying to do those is make it so the new author name is used on new commits, not just on previous stuff.

Comment: For the new name on the new commits, you have to change the username used to log in.

If the username and password were saved, go to the Tortoise settings, under "Saved Data" and click "Clear" on "Authentication data".

Comment: +1 for @Danny T's comment. You may also need to rename the Windows account name too.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you've tried changing the author name like sharptooth suggested, but then you probably received an error message stating that you couldn't.  This requires the implicit use of the `pre-revprop-change` hook.  By default this hook will always return an error unless you actually override the template and make an actual script that is capable of returning a zero-value.  From [svn-book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-revprop-change.html):

> The pre-revprop-change hook is run immediately prior to the modification of a revision
>   property when performed outside the scope of a normal commit. Unlike the other hooks,
>   the default state of this one is to deny the proposed action. The hook must actually exist
>   and return a zero exit value before a revision property modification can happen.

Here's a copy of my `pre-revprop-change` hook which allows me to edit the log message, but not the author:

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
USER="$3"
PROPNAME="$4"
ACTION="$5"

if [ "$ACTION" = "M" -a "$PROPNAME" = "svn:log" ]; then exit 0; fi
# if [ "$ACTION" = "M" -a "$PROPNAME" = "svn:author" ]; then exit 0; fi

echo "Changing revision properties other than svn:log and svn:author is prohibited" >&2
exit 1
```

To be able to change the author on a given revision, you would need to uncomment the second `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You'd change the author name in the repository, not on the individual client computers...

Tortoise SVN has an edit author capability in the right click context menu on the log window.