# Subclipse commit author

Tags: svn, commit, subclipse

Okay, so the author name that my commits happen under in Subclipse using SVN has unexpectedly changed from my username (which I have been using for the last 3 years) to 'svnsrvc', seemingly magically.

The only recent system changes related to Eclipse or Subversion that have occurred are: my Windows password had expired, and I had to put in my new password in order to access the repo; and we installed an update for VisualSVN on our subversion server. Other than that nothing has changed.

I have tried: making a new workplace; deleting the .keyring file; using a new version of Eclipse with a new workspace. Nothing changes this behaviour. There is no way I changed my repo login to 'svnsrvc' because I don't even know the password.

My OS is Win7, using Indigo Java EE with Subclipse plugin and cfEclipse plugin.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this before? I had thought that the author name could not be changed, ever.

Comment: Have you checked the information in your SVN client installation about passwords? This should be located under `c:\users\<username>\.subversion\auth\  or  c:\users\<username>\AppDate\Roaming\Subversion\auth`. Search in these directories for the string `svnsrvc`. I cannot explain where that should come from ...

Comment: Could not find svnsrvc, but you did put me on the right path, thanks!
In C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.simple I had two files.
-one should have a line that says "username" and then two lines down is your regular username. 
-the second file has a line that says "password" and two lines below was our admin password for VisualSVN. I figure I was being logged in as the VisualSVN admin. Delete this second file. You should be challenged for your password again, and then your name should again be stamped on your revisions.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be a change in the hooks of the server, like a `pre-revprop-change`, set to put the 'wrong' author name (or a [change in the Apache http server](http://subversion.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1065&dsMessageId=2372794)).
See "[Changing svn author property](http://home.introweb.nl/d/dodger/svnauthor.html)":

> Go to the '`hooks`' directory in your repository (eg. `/var/svn/my_repo/hooks/`), copy `pre-revprop-change.tmpl` to `pre-revprop-change`, edit the `pre-revprop-change` file to make sure setting the author is enabled (or see below), make the script executable (`chmod +x pre-revprop-change`) and you're done.

Check at least if this works to fix the revisions with the wrong author name (or do it [through TortoiseSVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042767/change-author-name-in-tortoisesvn)):

```
 $ svn propset --revprop -r revision_number svn:author your_username
```