# SVN Show Logs with no users in Tortoise “Show log” for properties change

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have noticed that sometimes we are missing user ID (“Author” column) when we use the Tortoise “Show log”. 
This happens when we change some properties on files or folders and we commit them. 
Is it possible to correct it or is this the normal behavior ?

Thanks[image: attached image is the screen shot where the author name is blank]

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Its not normal behaviour. The author (and log message) are properties themselves (called revprops), so maybe you've deleted the old entries when you edited the properties of the files.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2060178/13744) for a hook that will prevent author name changing.